# case insensitivity for routing in play framework 1.2.5

Tags: playframework-1.x

I am using play framework 1.2.5.  If I use camelCase for my controller names, the URL appears to follow the same format.  Is there anyway I can keep the camelcase for the controller names without needing to use camelCase in the resulting URL.  I believe I could try something like the following (regex in routes.conf) but I was wondering if there is another way:

```
[aA]dmin
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test on one of my projects and the catch all line

```
# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

is not case sensitive

So you could simply just use

```
# Catch all
*       /{action}                  MyController.{action}
```

If you wanted to expose the admin method as /Admin /admin or even /AdMiN